# How to get video from photoGallery using UIImagePickerController in iOS?

Tags: ios, uiimage

I want to get video from photoGallery when I click video button and which is displayed in same view. I have written this code, but don't get video into the imageview on same view.

```
- (IBAction)vedioClicked:(id)sender
{
imagePicker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
imagePicker.delegate = self;
imagePicker.allowsEditing = YES;

imagePicker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary;
imagePicker.mediaTypes =
[[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects: (NSString *) kUTTypeMovie, nil];
[self presentViewController:imagePicker animated:YES completion:nil];

}

- (void) imagePickerController: (UIImagePickerController *) picker  didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo: (NSDictionary *) info
{
NSString *mediaType = [info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerMediaType];

if ([mediaType isEqualToString:(NSString *)kUTTypeImage]) 

{
UIImage *editedImage = (UIImage *)[info objectForKey:@"UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage"];

// Compressing the image size

CGSize newSize = CGSizeMake(400, 400);
UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(newSize);
[editedImage drawInRect:CGRectMake(0,0,newSize.width,newSize.height)];

// Get the new image from the context
inputImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
self.imageView.image=inputImage;

// End the context

UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

NSData *data =  UIImageJPEGRepresentation(inputImage,0.2);//PNGRepresentation(imgView.image);

}
else if ([mediaType isEqualToString:@"public.movie"]){

NSURL *videoURL = [info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerMediaURL];

}
self.imageView.image=inputImage;   
[picker dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];

}
```

video is getting from photo library but its not display into imageView on same view so anybody help me to do this.Any help is more appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can't directly display video in UIImageView. If we try to load directly  it will display black screen only. To display video in UIImageView we need to load the first frame of video. For this need to import two frameworks.

1.AVFoundation

2.AssetsLibrary

Using these two we can display first frame of video into UIImageView as follows:

```
- (void) imagePickerController: (UIImagePickerController *) picker  didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo: (NSDictionary *) info
{
   NSString *mediaType = [info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerMediaType];

  if ([mediaType isEqualToString:(NSString *)kUTTypeImage]) 
  {
     UIImage *editedImage = (UIImage *)[info objectForKey:@"UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage"];

  // Compressing the image size

    CGSize newSize = CGSizeMake(400, 400);
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(newSize);
    [editedImage drawInRect:CGRectMake(0,0,newSize.width,newSize.height)];

   // Get the new image from the context
   inputImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
   self.imageView.image=inputImage;

   // End the context

    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

   NSData *data =  UIImageJPEGRepresentation(inputImage,0.2);//PNGRepresentation(imgView.image);

  }
  else if ([mediaType isEqualToString:@"public.movie"])
  {

    NSURL *videoURL = [info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerMediaURL];

    AVAsset *avAsset = [AVURLAsset URLAssetWithURL:videoURL options:nil];

    if ([[avAsset tracksWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeVideo] count] > 0)
    {
      AVAssetImageGenerator *imageGenerator =[AVAssetImageGenerator assetImageGeneratorWithAsset:avAsset];
      Float64 durationSeconds = CMTimeGetSeconds([avAsset duration]);
      CMTime midpoint = CMTimeMakeWithSeconds(durationSeconds/2.0, 600);
      NSError *error;
      CMTime actualTime;

      CGImageRef halfWayImage = [imageGenerator copyCGImageAtTime:kCMTimeZero actualTime:&actualTime error:&error];

      if (halfWayImage != NULL)
      {

         NSString *actualTimeString = (NSString *)CFBridgingRelease(CMTimeCopyDescription(NULL, actualTime));
         NSString *requestedTimeString = (NSString *)CFBridgingRelease(CMTimeCopyDescription(NULL, midpoint));
         NSLog(@"Got halfWayImage: Asked for %@, got %@", requestedTimeString, actualTimeString);

          UIImage *img=[UIImage imageWithCGImage:halfWayImage];
          self.imageView.image=img;

       }

     }
  }

   [picker dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];

}
```